# [Solved]How add actions in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, module

I create a new module and I would add actions in my module but how ?
[image]

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. I don't this is a duplicate. The op is asking about different actions.

Comment: @Marius you're totally right my bad, retracted my vote ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Spacename/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/yourlisitng.xml**

check this column and add action in that file `Spacename\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions`

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Spacename\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
```

**Spacename/Modulename/Ui/Componenet/Listing/Column/Youactionfile.php**

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['id' => $item['id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::CMS_URL_PATH_DELETE, ['id' => $item['id']]),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.title }'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.title } record?')
                        ]
                    ];
                  //add here
                }

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you build your module using the ui-components (as the image show) you need to add this at the end of your ui component file, before the `<columns>` tag is closed.

```
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\[Entity]Actions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">[entity]_id</item>
                <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">[entity]_id</item><!-- or the value could be 'id' here depending on how your edit link looks like. This is the name of the get parameter-->
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

Then create the class.  `[Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\[Entity]Actions`

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class [Entity]Actions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    /**
     * Url path  to edit
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'url/to_entity/edit_page'; 

    /**
     * Url path  to delete
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'url/to_entity/delete_page';

    /**
     * URL builder
     * 
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                if (isset($item['[entity]_id'])) {
                    $item[$this->getData('name')] = [
                        'edit' => [
                            'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_EDIT,
                                [
                                    '[entity]_id' => $item['[entity]_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Edit')
                        ],
                        'delete' => [
                            'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                static::URL_PATH_DELETE,
                                [
                                    '[entity]_id' => $item['[entity]_id']
                                ]
                            ),
                            'label' => __('Delete'),
                            'confirm' => [
                                'title' => __('Delete "${ $.$data.name }"'),
                                'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete the record "${ $.$data.name }" ?')
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.